# jni signature for method

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

My java method contains a function

```
 public static void downLoadProfileImage(String url, String fileName,  int tag, int from)
```

I am getting a JNI signature error:

```
if (JniHelper::getStaticMethodInfo(jniMethodInfo, packageName.c_str(), "downLoadProfileImage", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I;I;)V"))
```

If I just keep the two strings, everything works. But with two integers it throws an error? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't try to work these out by hand. Use 'javap -s'. It's never wrong.

Comment: One thing you can do is look in the logs; there will be a message about the function not being found, along with the signature(s) it tried to match.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The two integer markers (I) shouldn't have a following semicolon. Try:

```
(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;II)V
```

**Edit:** The best way to work is probably to use "javap -s" to have java print the signatures for you. Also make sure you read and understand [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html)

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you tell me when to and when not to use a ;

Comment: ; is an end marker used only in pair with L to mark the end of the class name.

Comment: `egrep` helps with `javap -s`. For example: `javap -s -public java.lang.String | egrep -A 2 "getBytes"`. On Windows, [GOW](http://chocolatey.org/packages/Gow) provides egrep.

Comment: Love the hint about using `javap -s`. Not sure why more people don't mention that. Thanks! You may want to provide an example and show that you point it to a `.class` file.

Comment: `V` stands for `void`. It’s easy to guess, but the link doesn’t mention `V` or `void`.

Comment: Good observation, I think (but that's just a guess) that the reason is that V wouldn't be used to pass values.